# Regular expression in Oracle to Filter particular charecters only

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I have a scenario

```
Case 1: "NO 41 ABC STREET"
Case 2: "42 XYZ STREET"
```

For almost 100 000 data in my table.

I want a regexp that

- omits '`NO 41`' and leaves back `ABC STREET` as output in case 1, whereas
- in case 2 I want  '`42 XYZ STREET`' as output.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_replace('NO 41 ABC STREET', 'NO [0-9]+ |([0-9]+)', '\1')` outputs `ABC STREET`.
`regexp_replace('42 XYZ STREET', 'NO [0-9]+ |([0-9]+)', '\1')` outputs `42 XYZ STREET`.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided only 2 scenarios of your data in the table. Assuming that you only want to replace the characters in a  column which starts with a "NO" followed by digit and then space before some other characters, you could use this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c6b35/5)

**Query**:

```
select s,REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'^NO +\d+ +') as r FROM data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c6b35/5/0)**:

```
|                S |             R |
|------------------|---------------|
| NO 41 ABC STREET |    ABC STREET |
|    42 XYZ STREET | 42 XYZ STREET |
```

If you have more complex data to be filtered, please edit your question and describe it clearly.